# Build APK Conflict with apache/http library

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I can run my application on devices using **USB**, But when i tried to build **APK** it's measure this error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/HttpHeaders.class

my gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "elryad.harajsooq"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.2.3'
        compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5'
    //    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    //    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    //    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
        compile files('libs/volley.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
        //compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:25.0.2'
        compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.0"
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.0'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Legacy Apache HTTP

You're bundling a version of Apache HTTP with your app. Remove this line from all modules' `build.gradle`:

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Behind the scenes that method actually includes a JAR of an old version of Apache HTTP which is not what you want if you're managing dependencies through Gradle/maven.

#### Matching versions

All imported artifacts from Apache HTTP have to have the same version.

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.3'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.5.3'
```

Well, `httpcore` does not follow this sheme, then again consider it an internal transitive dependency, appropriate version is pulled automatically by whatever version of `httpclient` you use. You don't have to specify it manually.

List of Apache HTTP artifacts in maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents

Comment: i used `'org.apache.http.legacy'` in many places in my application.. it there any way instead ?
and after i matched the version of apache.http it's throw another error :
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class` 

btw why i can install the app but i can't build apk ?

Comment: You're installing the old apk. Don't import Volley JAR you already import it thorugh maven. In fact you can probably import everything using maven instread of JAR. For more control remove `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` as well.